# Updating Bitmap from BackgroundWorker in MVVM/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, bitmap, backgroundworker

I'm trying to update a BitmapImage in the UI from a BackgroundWorker thread. I know enough about background workers to generally set them up, and how to use an ObservableCollection to update a list from a BackgroundWorker, but I'm struggling getting the image to update.

When I set

So far it looks like this:

XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private BitmapImage ImageSource_;
    public BitmapImage ImageSource
    {
        get { return ImageSource_; }
        set { ImageSource_= value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageSource"); }
    }

    private BackgroundWorker UpdateImageBGW = new BackgroundWorker();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        // this works fine
        ImageSource = UpdateImage();

        UpdateImageBGW.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(UpdateImage_DoWork);
        UpdateImageBGW.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void UpdateImage_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // this gets called fine and grabs the updated image, but setting it to
        // ImageSource never updates the UI
        ImageSource = UpdateImage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to update a UI element from a background thread. You cannot interact with elements created on the UI thread from any other thread because of security reasons. If you want to update the UI from a background thread, do something like this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate() { /*update UI thread here*/ });
```

This method will create the bridge that allows you to talk to the UI thread. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602567/how-to-update-ui-from-another-thread-running-in-another-class) stackoverflow thread that has more example.

Best of Luck

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. I actually understand how Dispatchers work now.

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ImageSource = UpdateImage());

Answer (score 0):

use ObservableCollection like this:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<int> myVar;

    public ObservableCollection<int> MyProperty
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { myVar = value; }
    }

    BackgroundWorker bw;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        MyProperty = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++)
       {
           MyProperty.Add(i);
       }
    }
}
```

and xaml:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty}" Height="224" Margin="93,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321"/>
```

Comment: I mentioned it briefly in the original post, but I know how to use ObservableCollection for updating a list. Is it possible to use them for updating just the Image Source binding, since it only needs a single object and not a list/collection?