# callback class to update wpf UI

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, user-interface

I am creating a chatting app using WCF-Duplex and WPF. Is there is any way to call a UI function when the callback method (which is in another class than the UI) is invoked from the server?!

Here is a sample of my classes:

Service:

```
[ServiceContract( 
    Name = "GPH_QuickMessageService",
    Namespace = "TextChat",
    SessionMode = SessionMode.Required,
    CallbackContract = typeof(IMessageServiceCallback))]

        public interface IMessageServiceInbound
        {
            [OperationContract]
            int JoinTheConversation(string userName);

        }   public interface IMessageServiceCallback
        {
            [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
            void NotifyUserJoinedTheConversation(string userName);
        }
```

The JoinTheConversation invokes NotifyUserJoinedTheConversation method at the client

The Client: 
The Form:

```
           public partial class Account : Window 
    {
      public Account()
        {
           InitializeComponent();

        }
      public void updateUsersInConversation(string username)
       {
             TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
             item.Header = username;
             contactsTree.Children.Add(item);
       }
   }
```

The callback implementation at the client

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class ChatCallBack : GPH_QuickMessageServiceCallback, IDisposable
{

    public ChatCallBack()
    {
        //UIContext = context;
    }

    public void NotifyUserJoinedTheConversation(string userName)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("IN CLIENT");
        //I want to call updateUsersInConversation in the UI class
    }
  }
```

I searched alot and found a lot of things about delegation and SendOrPostCallBack but I just couldn't link all these things together. I am sorry for the long post and hope anyone can help me with that

Comment: what is ChatCallBack here? XAML?

Comment: It is the class that implements the callback functions for the WCF service at the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `Dispatcher.Invoke()` inside an Event Handler registered in your Account class.

More info here: [How to update UI from another thread running in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602567/how-to-update-ui-from-another-thread-running-in-another-class)

[Edit] Some code example:

```
class ChatCallBack 
{
    public event EventHandler<string> UserJoinedTheConversation;

    public void NotifyUserJoinedTheConversation(string username)
    {
        var evt = UserJoinedTheConversation;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, username);
    }

    //other code
}
```

And in you Account Class:

```
private ChatCallBack chatCallBack;
public Account() //class constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    chatCallBack = new ChatCallBack();
    chatCallBack.UserJoinedTheConversation += (sender, username) =>
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => updateUsersInConversation(username));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

Create a method to return the Instance of the MainWindow,

```
 public static Account _this;

        public Account()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _this = this;

        }
        public void updateUsersInConversation(string username)
        {
            TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
            item.Header = username;
            //contactsTree.Children.Add(item);
        }
        public  static Account GetInstance()
        {
            return _this;
        }
```

And in your Client call back class, you can invoke the method like this

```
        public void NotifyUserJoinedTheConversation(string userName)
        {
          Account temp = Account.GetInstance();
          temp.updateUsersInConversation("test");
        }
```

Comment: It gives me an error saying that I can't update the UI elements because it is in a different thread.