# MVVM: Setting ViewModel from XAML leads to error where from Code-behind doesn't

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am starting a Window from a different application. Whenever I start the Window, it is done from a different thread. The first time I start the Window, everything works fine. Every later attempt fails with the error: `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

I used to assign the DataContext in the Xaml like this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MyViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

The error stopped, when I changed it to assign the ViewModel from the code behind like this:

```
public MyView() {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MyViewModel();
}
```

According to an [answer at MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/37f2b458-127d-4e12-82c8-419103f08c6b/setting-datacontext-in-xaml-mvvm?forum=wpf) these two approaches should be equivalent.

Why do I get different results? Is there a way to make my first approach work (as I would prefer it)?

**Edit:**

The control is initialized in another Xaml:

```
<userControls:MyView Grid.Column="2" x:Name="MyView" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" ></userControls:MyView>
```

The window itself is started using

```
AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
    MyMainWindow form = new MyMainWindow(someObject);
    form.Closed += (sender2, e2) => {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        are.Set();
    };
    form.Show();
    Dispatcher.Run();
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
are.WaitOne();
```

**Edit 2:**

After some debugging I found the root cause. I was using a custom implementation of a messaging system based on the [Prism Event Aggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx). When MyMainWindow was closed, I didn't clear all the subscriptions.

Comment: To quote: *"Whenever I start the Window, it is done from a different thread."* and the error: *"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"*. It seems to be **quite clear** what the issue is here. Create your `MyView` on the **UI Thread**, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602567/how-to-update-ui-from-another-thread-running-in-another-class).

Comment: Show us how you create your view

Comment: @MikeEason Thanks for your suggestion. I realize that the threading is to blame for the error, yet I find it puzzling that one method works, while they other one doesn't even though they should be equivalent.

Comment: @Tomtom I added the information you asked for.

Comment: *"The window itself is started using"* wat

Comment: There is almost **NEVER** a case where you need to handle threads yourself. This isn't C++.  With the TPL you get all you need to easily handle async operations or background work and with await/async you can even write your code in an sync manner. As for the reason, UI objects can only be created and modified from the UI Thread, nothing else.